# Trigger is not working

Tags: trigger, class, before-trigger

I am new in salesforce and i am trying to get regions to Auth Object From Contact's county.County object has county and region and Contact object has a lookup to County object.

Auth object has a lookup to Contact object.Child is Auth.

**Auth**(contact(lookup),region)

**Contact**(county(lookup) )

**County**(County,region)

And what is wrong with this trigger and class ?

```
public class RegionTriggerHandler{

    public static void insertReg(Set<String> counties){

        Map<string,county__c> CountyToRegionMap = new Map <String,county__c> ();
        List < county__c> regionList ;

        if(counties.size()>0){
            regionList=[SELECT id,ZipCodeNo__c,Name,Region__c from County__c where Name IN:counties];
        }

        for(county__c c1: regionList){
            CountyToRegionMap.put(c1.Name,c1);
        }

        for(Auth__c c:(List<Auth__c>)trigger.new){

            if(CountyToRegionMap.get(c.Contact__r.County__c)!=NULL){

                c.Region__c=CountyToRegionMap.get(c.Contact__r.County__c).Region__c;

            }
        }
    }
```

-

```
trigger TriggerForGettingRAuth on Auth__c (before insert,before update) {
set<string> counties = new set<string>();
for(Auth__C c:trigger.new){
    counties.add(c.Contact__r.county__c);
}

if(trigger.isBefore&&trigger.isInsert){
    RegionTriggerHandler.insertReg(counties);

}

if(trigger.isBefore&&trigger.isUpdate){
            RegionTriggerHandler.insertReg(counties);

}

}
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: there is nothing

Comment: When create or update a Auth object that is related to a Contact, it does not fill in the Region field? Does the County record exist and have exactly the same name?

Comment: yes it does not fill region field when create and update Auth, and also county record exists and have exactly same name.

Comment: I do not see anything obvious that is incorrect. I would add some System.debug() statements to make sure you are to your insertReg method, what the counties variable is, and what the results of your query are, and if you are finding the record in your map.